# Visual Studio, Xutility error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors

I am trying to code a simple program using std, but, whenever I do visual studio gives an error based in the Xutility file.

the file is basic but, I wanted to test out some functions this is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

std::string text = "racecar", temp, revText;
bool yes;

void init(){
 //std::cin >> text  ;
 reverseFunction(text);}

void reverseFunction(std::string userWord){
 std::reverse(userWord, revText);}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
 init();}
```

I am using VS 2015 but I installed 2017 on a new laptop and both have the same problem... these are the errors that I am given

> C2794  'iterator_category': is not a member of any direct or indirect base class of 'std::iterator_traits<_InIt>'  Project1    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xutility 967 
>   Error
>   C2938   '_Iter_cat_t' : Failed to specialize alias template    Project1    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xutility 967 
>   Error
>   C2062   type 'unknown-type' unexpected  Project1    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xutility 967 
>   Error
>   C2675   unary '--': 'std::string' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator Project1    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xutility 3547
>   Error
>   C2675   unary '++': 'std::string' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator Project1    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xutility 3547

is there any fix for this as I have two machines, running different versions and both have the same problem and I can't compile with the errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this version of the code fixes it ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

std::string text = "racecar", temp, revText;
bool yes;

void reverseFunction(std::string userWord)
{
    revText = userWord;
    std::reverse(revText.begin(), revText.end());
}

void init()
{
    //std::cin >> text  ;
    reverseFunction(text);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    init();
}
```

There were some errors:

- `string` and `algorithm` includes were missing
- `reverseFunction()` was defined *after* `init()`, hence the compiler could not find it
- According to [the docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse),  `std::reverse` takes the `begin` and `end` iterators as parameters, and not the string you want to reverse and where you want to store it. There are to reasons for this:

  1- The data transformation is done in-place,

  2- The STL algorithms are meant to be generic and container agnostic: they should work on any collection that is somehow iterable. To convince yourself you can try this piece of code out:

  ```
  #include <algorithm>
  #include <iostream>

  int main()
  {
      int t[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
      int len = sizeof t / sizeof(int);

      std::cout << "Before: ";
      for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) std::cout << t[i] << " ";
      std::cout << std::endl;

      std::reverse(t, t + len);
      std::cout << "After:  ";
      for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) std::cout << t[i] << " ";
      std::cout << std::endl;

      return 0;
  }
  ```

This should give you the following output:

```
Before: 0 1 2 3 4 5 
After:  5 4 3 2 1 0
```

As you can see, the algorithm still works, even if we are not using STL containers, we just provided *iterator-like* inputs.

Comment: adding in the #include algorithm works. the setup I am using is multiple files for each function, this is why the reverseFunction() comes before the inti() as they are in different files but I pit them all in the one for this... as for the actual function that was supposed to be removed from the version I was trying to run was just using std and strings and giving me errors... thank you for your help